# I run zsh from bash after connecting SSH – how can I exit both with only one command?

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh

I run zsh on my server and I want to alias the `exit` command, because whenever I try to terminate my SSH session I must exit from `zsh` and exit from `bash`.

I tried `alias exit='exit;exit'` to no avail.

I don't want to change how I start `zsh` but I think it's not a very good solution. I've appended `zsh` to `/etc/profile`.

How can avoid to type `exit` twice to terminate my SSH session?

Comment: Try pressing ctrl+d twice, it should log you out of a terminal as well.

Comment: To clarify, `bash` is your login shell and you run zsh by manually starting it? Have you considered making `zsh` your login shell or running it using the `exec` built-in, *replacing* the `bash` process?

Comment: When I want to change how to start zsh do I have to append zsh to ~/.bashrc? How can I completley replace bash?

Comment: @Daniel: How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`bash` is the default login shell of your account on that system. To change it, do what @KevinPanko suggests. Then `bash` won't start, only `zsh`. Given that, through `/etc/profile`, you're always starting `zsh` at the moment (and not just sometimes), that would probably the best way to do it.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `exec` built-in command of `bash` to replace your `bash` process. `man bash` states:

> `exec ... [command [arguments]]`
>
> If command is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.  The arguments become the arguments to command.

So you can run `zsh` like this:

```
exec zsh
```

Afterwards, if you exit `zsh`, you exit the only shell you're running, and quit immediately.

Comment: When I use chsh can I break something? Can I start a SSH session when I break something, I mean when bash or zsh and both doesn't load anymore? Is there a failsafe to SSH?

Comment: You can give SSH a command to run:  `ssh -t hostname /bin/bash`

Comment: @jitamaro direct access to the machine or log in as a different user is your fail safe. If you actually manage to mess up your shell binary, you'll have been making stupid mistakes as root and deserve to restore from backup ;)

Comment: @Dainiel: I don't have physical access to that box and I have only one user (root). It's a good practise to create another user or give SSH a command to run?

Comment: @jitamaro do not run as root unless you absolutely have to and know what you're doing. No offence, but it sounds like you might profit from reading a tutorial or two about Linux use..? That'll explain why multiple users are a good thing,

Comment: @Daniel: It's becomeing a bad habit of me but I'm a very experienced user. I know the difference of elevated privilege mostly from programming assembler and CPU and I will consider your advise.

Answer (score 5):

The `chsh` command lets you change the login shell on your account.

You might need to add `/bin/zsh` to your `/etc/shells` file if it is not there already.

Comment: If the server you connect to uses LDAP or similar, you'll have to use the `ypchsh` command instead.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this problem, just add the script below to the `.bashrc` file:

```
if test -t 1; then
  exec zsh
fi
```

Note: Performed on Ubuntu 10.04 and Debian 10, but I believe it works on other linux destructions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).